# Android: best way to control view that added dynamically?

Tags: android, android-view

As the title, i want to know if there is a the best way to control a view that added dynamically. (we have to keep reference to the view that was added)

Some time, for a complex request we have to add view in runtime. The is some ways to do that. In my case:

1. Some time i use a `listview/recyclerview` and `control view` via the `list/recycleview adapter`.
2. Other way is use a `hashmap`.

Do you have any other ideas? and how it work?

Comment: You can use the  LayoutInflator to create a view based on your layout template, and then inject it into the view where you need it.

Comment: I know, so i think that i need to change the question litle bit. The main point is the way to control the view that added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer way, when I define View both by Java and XML file. View created like this, gives you ability to call your own Java methods, but you don`t need to create whole layout dynamically in Java. Little example:

**MyView.java:**

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {

    TextView textView;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.my_view, this);
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    public MyView setContent(String value) {
        textView.setText(value);

        return this;
    }
}
```

**my_view.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</merge>
```

After that, you can simply add it in you layout through Java:

```
cont.addView(new MyView(this).setContent("Value"));
```

or xml:

```
<com.path.to.your.view.MyView
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: nice idea! and, i'm thinking about create new function to get all values from your view. so excited!

Comment: @LạngHoàng Sure, that's absolutely possible.

Comment: your solution help me alot. thank for sharing it. But i still want to let this question open for a time if anybody have another solution for that.  Then i'm going to make your answer as accept answer :)